# python import csv every week

Tags: python, csv

I need help importing a weekly file which is named example this week:  filename_20191130,
last week filename_20191123. Basically, it is named based on the date of every Saturday. I need to import files going back 3 weeks.

Example, if I run the program today- I need to import csv named filename_20191130, filename_20191123, filename_20191116

What I tried for today's file but isn't working

```
 from datetime import datetime, timedelta
 thisweek =datetime.now().date().strftime("%Y%m%d%")

df = pd.read_csv('filename_' + thisweek.csv, header = 0)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more detail regarding how it "isn't working"?

Comment: Why isn't it working?  Did you get an error?  What output did you see?  Do you have some sample data for someone to work off of?  The way your question is articulated no one can help you

Comment: @JCP you are missing quotes around `.csv` in your call to `pd.read_csv`. Try `df = pd.read_csv('filename_' + thisweek + '.csv', header = 0)` this instead.

Comment: Today is Dec-2, yet the first filename is supposed to be `filename_20191130.csv`, so I presume the first filename is based on the first weekday (Holidays included) preceding today?

Comment: pd.read_csv(f'filename_{thisweek}.csv', header = 0)

Comment: thisweek =datetime.now().date().strftime("%Y%m%d%") - I realized, this itself is incorrect to start with. Here, thisweek = 20191202 when I need date to last Saturday i.e 20191130

Comment: What are the rules for the lookback?

Comment: for lookback : no matter what day of the week I run the date should refer to Saturday's date. Example if I run it tomorrow or day after - the date should still refer to 20191130 which is last saturday.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an extra "%" at the end of your string formatting. Additionally, you are incorrectly concatenating .csv to the end of the filename. ".csv" needs to be a string.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> thisweek = datetime.now().date().strftime("%Y%m%d%")
>>> file = "filename_" + thisweek + ".csv"
>>> print(file)
filename_20191202%.csv
```

Should be:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> thisweek = datetime.now().date().strftime("%Y%m%d")
>>> file = "filename_" + thisweek + ".csv"
>>> print(file)
filename_20191202.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

last_week = 3

today = datetime.today()
last_saturday = today - timedelta(days=(today.day))

for week in range(last_week):
    week_saturday = last_saturday - timedelta(days=7 * week)
    file_saturday = week_saturday.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    df = pd.read_csv(f"filename_{file_saturday}.csv", header=0)
    .....
```

or set number of weeks

```
weeks = 3
today = datetime.today()
last_saturday = today - timedelta(days=(today.day))
week_saturday = last_saturday - timedelta(days=7 * weeks)
file_saturday = week_saturday.strftime("%Y%m%d")
df = pd.read_csv(f"filename_{file_saturday}.csv", header=0)
```